# Один реквизит в два элемента формы с разными данными

Tags: 1с

1с 8.3 управляемое приложение

Есть табличная часть с данными. На форме документа имеется 2 элемента этой табличной части. Необходимо установить два отбора на данные реквизита таким образом, чтобы при выводе данные в первом элементе формы реквизита табличной части соответствовали первому отбору, а во втором - второму отбору.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Была идея такая:

```
1) установить первый отбор
2) получить данные
3) выгрузить данные в первый элемент формы
4) удалить отбор
5) установить новый отбор
6) получить данные
7) выгрузить данные во второй элемент формы
```

таким образом, реквизит формы один, а элемента 2 с разными данными.

Как можно всё это сделать иначе?

Comment: Иначе можно сделать обычным Запросом "... ГДЕ Документ.ИмяТЧ.Признак = &Признак" ; Для первой тч Формы делаем Запрос.УстановитьПараметр("Признак", ПризнакНаПечи) а для второй соответственно ПризнакНаФакел

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё оказалось намного проще:)

```
Элементы.РезультатыПечи.ОтборСтрок = Новый ФиксированнаяСтруктура("Позиция", "ПечиЭЛОУ");
Элементы.РезультатыФакел.ОтборСтрок = Новый ФиксированнаяСтруктура("Позиция", "Факел");
```